# Why can variables be assigned to interface type?

Tags: java, interface, instantiation

I'm new to Java and am trying to learn the concept of interface. I saw the code below online. I understand that interface can't be instantiated. My question is, WatchService, Path, WatchKey and WatchEvent are all interface, how come variables can be assigned to interface type? Is is the same as instantiation?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

public class WatchServices {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        WatchService ws1 = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

        Path p1 = Paths.get("/Users/justin/Desktop/Codes Netbean/JavaRandom");

        WatchKey wk1 = p1.register(ws1, ENTRY_CREATE);

        while(true){
            for(WatchEvent<?> event : wk1.pollEvents()){
                System.out.println(event.kind());
                Path file  = (Path)event.context();
                System.out.println(file);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You are confusing the compile time type with the run time type. Declaring a variable defines it's compile time type - at run time, any compatible reference can be assigned to it. An `interface` specifies a _contact_ that the object referenced must satisfy. So `WatchService` is an `interface`, we know that at runtime `FileSystems.newWatchService()` will return some value that implements that `interface` - but we don't know the exact type as that may well be platform dependant. For other examples see the `Collection` framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer you with an example.

Suppose that I ask you to bring me a [sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere). You then bring me a beach ball.

A sphere doesn't exist, it's a concept, a geometrical object and a beach ball is a material object which can be considered a sphere.

That's approximately the same thing, an `interface` defines the characteristics of an object through its exposed interface (the methods that can be called on an object which pretend to `implement` that interface) but it's not a material object per se.

So I can consider a beach ball as a sphere even if the sphere doesn't exist. It doesn't make any sense to instantiate a sphere, since a sphere can't be instantiated, but I can treat a beach ball as a sphere.

Comment: I like your answer much better than my own - it's short, simple, and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

An interface defines a set of methods that can be called, but does not implement them. That is why you can never say `Runnable x = new Runnable()`. A class can be defined, which implements all the methods in the interface. It also has to declare that it implements that interface:

```
interface Runnable {
    public void run();
}

public class RandomTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Doing some stuff...");
    }

    public void shout() {
        System.out.println("DOING STUFF...");
    }
}
```

See how the class *implements* the interface. So a RandomTask *is* runnable, and therefore you can assign a RandomTask where a Runnable was expected:

```
Runnable x = new RandomTask();
```

The interface tells you what methods must exist on that object. We know that `x` must have a `run()` method, because it is a Runnable. So we can say

```
x.run();
```

Now, while *you* the programmer know that x has a `shout()` method, you can't access it anymore. By assigning `x` to a Runnable, you limit it to have only the methods that are defined for a Runnable.