# Assigning object of some class that implements Interface to a type Interface

Tags: java, oop

The title is a bit long so i will use some code to explain my question:

Let's say that I have a class **'Team'** that implements interface **ManageableTeam**. 
**ManagableTeam** has the following methods:

```
public boolean isPlayerRegistered(FootballPlayer player);
public boolean registerPlayer(FootballPlayer player);
public void setFormation(Formation formation);
```

- In class **Team** i have Overridden the above methods, but I have some other methods like:

`public boolean isPlayerReady(FootballPlayer player)`;

-Now if In some other class, I have following field:

```
ManageableTeam managingTeam;
```

and method:

```
public void setManagingTeam (ManageableTeam team){
       this.managingTeam = team;
   }
```

-Will assigning object of class Team to a object of type ManageableTeam make an Object that can only use 3 methods that were declared in interface ManageableTeam?

Like will ManageableTeam managingTeam = new Team(); make an object that can only use methods declared in interface ManageableTeam and not methods that are not declared in interface for example isPlayerReady method?

Comment: Your `managingTeam` field is a reference that can point to an object of an implementing type -- such as a Team object. Through the field, you can access only the methods declared or inherited for the field's type. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352254/why-can-variables-be-assigned-to-interface-type .

Answer (score 0):

you can cast an object to the class type like this:

```
 this.managingTeam = (Team)team;
```

in such case all the methos of class Teal will be avaliable.
But first you should better check if team instanceof Team